# ffmpeg get best quality

Tags: ffmpeg

how do i use ffmpeg to encode slowly for better quality?

I'm currently using this:

```
ffmpeg -i "input" -c:v hevc_qsv -b:v 1M -preset veryslow -t 5:00 "output"
```

Comment: Welcome the site. What do you mean with "better quality"?

Comment: I mean to get more quality for the same amount of data used,
just like how in obs selecting a slower preset gets better quality with the same bitrate

Comment: There's no such thing as universal "best quality". As for you question it's better to ask it here or here: https://forum.doom9.org/forumdisplay.php?f=81 https://forum.videohelp.com/forums/11-Video-Conversion